# TabBarItem Badge Value not shown

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

I wrote this code, but it seems not working and I don't know why, TabBarItem is the right one, but badge is not shown.

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBar") as! UITabBarController
let tabArray = tabBarController.tabBar.items as NSArray!
var chatItem = tabArray.objectAtIndex(3) as! UITabBarItem
chatItem.badgeValue = "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload tabBarController when you update value, So do like :

```
let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBar") as! TabsViewController // Your tabor controller
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2 // Whatever your selected index

let tabArray = tabBarController.tabBar.items as NSArray!
let chatItem = tabArray.objectAtIndex(3) as! UITabBarItem
chatItem.badgeValue = "1"
var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```